# ASP.NET MVC Editor-Templates/UIHint with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been using Editor-Templates in the past like this, by applying the following data annotation:

```
[UIHint("SomeTemplate")]
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 public class MicroViewModel
 {
    public IEnumerable<LabMicro> Micros { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DateTime")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int CaseNo { get; set; }

    [UIHint("SampleTypes")]
    public int LabSampleTypeID { get; set; }

    [UIHint("SampleDetails")]
    public int LabSampleDetailID { get; set; }
 }
```

If I wanted to use a specific date picker control as opposed to the regular one, it can be implemented as follows.

**Example:**

```
@model DateTime?    
@Html.TextBox("",  String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.HasValue ? 
        Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp", style="width:100px" })

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $(".dp").datepicker({    
            changeMonth: true,    
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'    
        });    
    });      
</script>
```

For my ID fields, I'd like to make use of the jQuery auto-complete component.

**Question:**

How would I go about passing additional parameters to the `UIHint` partial view for `LabSampleTypeID` and `LabSampleDetailID`? *(As Id like to have an auto-complete Editor-Template that'll take a URL and property names for example)*

**What I think my auto-complete Editor-Template/Partial should look like:**

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '[#URL_TO_USE]',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                filter: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(eval(data), function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.[#PROPERTY_TO_USE]
                    }
                }));
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the UIHint for the DateTime.  It's *already* a DateTime, so it will already use a DateTime.cshtml template if it exists.  You do need it for the other ones that are not the same type as the template name.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use the `AdditionalMetadata` attribute:

```
[UIHint("DateTime")]
[AdditionalMetadata("foo", "bar")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and in the template:

```
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["foo"]
```

so if you wanted to pass an url:

```
[UIHint("DateTime")]
[AdditionalMetadata("controller", "somecontroller")]
[AdditionalMetadata("action", "someaction")]
[AdditionalMetadata("property", "someproperty")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and in your template:

```
@{
    var values = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.auto').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action((string)values["action"], (string)values["controller"])',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                filter: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(
                    $.map(eval(data), function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item['@values["property"]']
                        }
                    })
                );
            }
        });
    }                    
});
</script>
```

Comment: `UHint` class has constructor with additional `params object[] controlParameters`. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: `UHint` controlParameters seems to be more sutable for this

Answer (score 4):

You could use the UHint without AdditionalMetadata attribute, but some additional code is requred

```
[UIHint("DateTime", null, "key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

override CreateMetadata:

```
public class CustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
    {
        public const string UiHintControlParameters = "UiHintControlParameters";

        protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
            IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
            Type containerType,
            Func<object> modelAccessor,
            Type modelType,
            string propertyName)
        {

            ModelMetadata metadata = base.CreateMetadata(
                attributes,
                containerType,
                modelAccessor,
                modelType,
                propertyName);

            IEnumerable<UIHintAttribute> uiHintAttributes = attributes.OfType<UIHintAttribute>();
            UIHintAttribute uiHintAttribute = uiHintAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals(a.PresentationLayer, "MVC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                              ?? uiHintAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.PresentationLayer));
            if (uiHintAttribute != null)
            {
                metadata.AdditionalValues.Add(UiHintControlParameters, uiHintAttribute.ControlParameters);
            }

            return metadata;
        }
```

Register CustomMetadataProvider:

```
    public static void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomMetadataProvider();
    }
```

and in your template:

```
    @{
        IDictionary<string, object> values = (IDictionary<string, object>)
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues[CustomMetadataProvider.UiHintControlParameters];
    }
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code but on attempting to register the custom provider it says it's unable to convert target type to System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider, any ideas?

Comment: The override that we created is extending from 'DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider' just like your example, but the 'ModelMetadataProviders.Current' is expecting a ModelMetadataProvider.

Comment: **Ciaran**, enshure you override `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, not `System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers`