# ASP.NET Differentiate between Date and Datetime Fields

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, format

I have an ASP.NET form(MVC3/Razor) and on the the form I want to alter how a date field displays from a datetime field.  I.e. in some of the data columns the time is significant and I want the date and time to show, in others it is irrelevant and I just want the date to display.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways: 1) Using a `UIHint` attribute to tell the field whether or not to render as a `Date` or `DateTime` and then having an `EditorTemplate` to differentiate the two.  Or 2) Use the `EditorFor` extension method and tell it explicitly which `EditorTemplate` to use.

The same can go for `DisplayTemplates` when you want to truncate the time.

Here's an example from SO: [ASP.NET MVC Editor-Templates/UIHint with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681107/asp-net-mvc-editortemplates-uihint-with-parameters)

Comment: This is better than the string.format, as it is applied to each field automatically.  I went for the 1) Using a UIHint attribute... solution and works well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.Format to format the date and time in exactly the way you want.

```
string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}", yourDate);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can format each appropriate column as you want. For example:

```
@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",DateTimeField)
```

and/or

```
@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}",DateTimeField)
```